# Practical offers of support when leaving a team

Tags: resignation, team, united-kingdom

I'm currently the manager of a small team (4 people) in a mid-sized organisation.

Having recently handed in my notice, I want to make the transition as smooth as possible for my colleagues.

What practical things / help / support can I offer them?

Comment: You might get some answers from well meaning members, but strictly speaking, your question is out of scope for Workplace SE. I'm sure there's plenty of articles out there on this exact topic ...

Comment: @AndreiROM Apologies if it's off topic. I read the FAQ and came to a different conclusion, but I suppose it's always a judgement call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, get any outstanding admin or HR out of the way. If your team member has an upcoming appraisal, get it done.

Next, document. Document your processes, your internal contacts, your team members' contact info, everything. Put it all in a passworded zip, or a secured folder on the domain storage and share it with your boss.

Finally, arrange a farewell. This way, people who might have forgotten you are leaving will be fully aware. Make sure you buy at least a round.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me few times, when managers leave they don't communicate level of efforts made by different employees.

Ideally managers should be communicating progress made by staff under them to higher management or to manager who will be taking over, but unfortunately this didn't happened to me.

So if you have any staff who you see has the potential to move forward than do recommend them to your boss.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add an answer to collate some of the offline suggestions I've been given...

- Offer to write LinkedIn recommendations